# Error to import tkinter

Tags: python

I try to import tkinter after i installed its library ,but i face this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
    import re
  File "/home/mohammed/re.py", line 5, in <module>
    if re.search('From:', line):
AttributeError: module 're' has no attribute 'search'
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 53, in apport_excepthook
    if not enabled():
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 24, in enabled
    import re
  File "/home/mohammed/re.py", line 5, in <module>
    if re.search('From:', line):
AttributeError: module 're' has no attribute 'search'
```

Original exception was:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
    import re
  File "/home/mohammed/re.py", line 5, in <module>
    if re.search('From:', line):
AttributeError: module 're' has no attribute 'search'
```

Comment: Try re-naming your python script to something other than `re.py`

Comment: @steeldriver :P

Comment: I didn't make a python script ,i just try to import tkinter

Comment: So what is `/home/mohammed/re.py`?

Comment: thanks , this was an old file and i deleted no error now

Answer (score 1):

You can  not have a module re and a python program called re. The program overrules the module.